# D7 to D8 users migration processes 0 items

Tags: 8, migrations

I am working on my first migration from D7 to D8. I am trying to keep it very simple and start with users. I have created a custom module migrate_custom, created my definition at config/install/migrate.migration.d7cafe_users.yml:

```
id: d7cafe_users
label: User accounts
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
source:
  plugin: d7cafe_users
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
process:
  uid: uid
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  created: created
  access: access
  login: login
  status: status
  timezone: timezone
  langcode: language
  init: init
```

Then I have my source plugin at src/plugin/migrate/source/User.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\migrate_custom\Plugin\migrate\source\User.
 */

namespace Drupal\migrate_custom\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SqlBase;

/**
 * Extract users from Drupal 7 database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "d7cafe_users"
 * )
 */
class User extends SqlBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    return $this->select('dcf_users', 'dcf_u')
      ->fields('dcf_u', ['uid', 'status', 'created','access', 'login',    'name',
        'pass', 'mail', 'init', 'language']);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields() {
    $fields = [
      'uid' => $this->t('Account ID'),
      'status' => $this->t('Blocked/Allowed'),
      'created' => $this->t('Registered date'),
      'access' => $this->t('Time of last access'),
      'login' => $this->t('Time of last login'),
      'name' => $this->t('Account name (for login)'),
      'pass' => $this->t('Account password (raw)'),
      'mail' => $this->t('Account email'),
      'init' => $this->t('init'),
      'language' => $this->t('language'),
    ];

    return $fields;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds() {
    return [
      'uid' => [
        'type' => 'integer',
        'alias' => 'dcf_u',
      ],
    ];
  }

}
?>
```

And finally I have a manifest.yml file containing:

```
- d7cafe_users
```

I run the migration with:

```
drush migrate-manifest manifest.yml --legacy-db-url=mysql://root:root@localhost/d7cafe
```

But all I get on command line is:

```
Running d7cafe_users                                                                                                                                                         [ok]
Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'd7cafe_users'
```

I don't think I'm far off, as I could see running it and importing the 4 users from the legacy db, but did a bit of fiddling on the definition file and now I can't get it back to importing records. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tried it on a new site install and the code works and migrates users perfectly. All I can think of is that db got corrupted after running migration and rolling back a number of times.

Comment: It would be better to keep a backup before running migration so that you can restore in this situation instead of reinstalling same site again and again.

Take a backup using "drupal dbdu" and restore same backup using "drupal dbr --file=name_of_backup_file.sql"